# How to read PDF files with text reflow

Tags: 8.0, pdf

Adobe Reader for Pocket PC 2.0 had a powerful text "Reflow" feature to wrap text at the screen boundary to enable reading on small screens.

The current readers for Windows Phone 8 do not seem to have this feature. Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Android OS had it too....We can just hope that Adobe will launch an update pretty soon...Also no remembering page number when entering app after a while....
Anyone has an alternative app?

Comment: After much gnashing and gnawing of teeth, I finally gave up on a reflow app reader for PDF files. What I did was converted the PDF I wanted to read on my phone to a Word doc (if you have a version of Word that will do this). Then use Windows Mobile Word to open. You can resize the text to something you like for your mobile screen, and it will automatically reflow it as well so you don't have to scroll left to right. This is just one of the reasons why I am not happy I purchased a Windows Phone now. Too many missing features that Android and iPhone have tons of apps already developed. The synch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suggestion from the user "kanagucdm" was helpful to me.

http://www.windowscentral.com/enjoying-good-book-your-windows-phone

Nokia Reading is the best app when reading a PDF in Windows Phone.
How to download:

1. In the Windows Phone settings change the region to UK.
2. Restart the phone
3. Go to the Store and download the app 'Nokia Reading'
4. Place your PDF files in OneDrive.
5. In the Nokia Reading app go to Mybooks and press the download button, enter your OneDrive credentials.
6. Download the books to your phone and read.

Pros:

- Nokia Reading nicely does the Text reflow for the PDF files  in the Windows Phone 8. Lumia 920 is awesome for this.
- Ebook Reader from Ebooks.com is a fantastic app for reading books, but only the books purchased from that site can be read.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not something that is possible at this time on Windows Phone. It's not just the `.pdf` readers on Windows Phone that do not have text re-flow- even Internet Explorer on Windows Phone does not have this feature.

[There are a whole bunch of feature suggestions provided here on the official Microsoft "User Voice" site surrounding the text-reflow here](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions?query=reflow). In fact, one of these feature suggestions has almost a 1000 upvotes.

Your best bet it to add a feature suggestion that asks for text-reflow to be built in to the native `Reader` app.